# jQuery Calendar event inside event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am working on a project. In my requirement, there is resource schedule (for example, X-ray machine is available for 8:00 AM Open-time to 9:00 PM Close-time). This resource schedule should be visible on calendar.
Now there can be patient appointments against this resource. So these appointment block should be come inside resource schedule block.

How can i achieve this functionality.

Comment: Please elborate with code or specify what you have already tried

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event from 0800-2100 and render it in one color (say grey or green). Then  just add events for appts with usage hours, and render them differently (say red), which will appear on top.

Another way: add events in 15min (or whatever) intervals, and mark them as available. As these are clicked, mark them as occupied (in your DB) and render them differently.

Comment: The thing is that there is possibility of multiple resource.